# Why does my Laravel website take about 25 seconds to load the first page?

Tags: laravel, http, nginx

If I'm not visiting my Laravel website for a long time, it takes so long to handle the first request (which redirects to the home page). Here is a screenshot of the network activity from developer tools.

[image: Network activity]

The website is hosted on an nginx server on infinityfree.net. Why would it take the server 25 seconds to just redirect to another page?

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` to autoload composer classmap and `php artisan optimzie` to clear caches. Is it only about the home page? Are all other pages working good?

Comment: Yes, the other pages are working good. Also if I reload the home page it works good. The problem happens if it has been a long time since I last visited the home page (i.e. if no session is established)

Comment: Then there may be so much load in home page. Is it requesting so much data from db or downloading high quality images